# Animated Image Slider is flickering in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I have an image slider that is flickering the previous image RIGHT after it slides to the next image. For some reason it is only doing this in google Chrome though. The slider setup is a Div with three separate images sitting side by side, and their location is translated with a jquery transition so that a different image is displaying. You can view this, and the flickering at www.cutephilosophy.com. (The slider is normally on auto-run but I turned that off for this question, just click the next or previous button to see the flickering).

CSS W/ JQUERY TRANSITION-

```
.slider{
    width: 960px;
    height: 450px;
    float:left;
}  
p#slide1_controls {
    text-align:center;
}
#slide1_controls span {
    padding-right:2em;
    cursor:pointer;
}
#slide1_container {
    width:690px;
    height:400px;
    float: left;
    overflow:hidden;
    /*margin:0 auto;*/
}
#slide1_images {
    float:left;
    width:2070px;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.505, 0.010, 0.455, 0.980); 
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.505, 0.010, 0.455, 0.980); 
    -ms-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.505, 0.010, 0.455, 0.980); 
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.505, 0.010, 0.455, 0.980); 
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.505, 0.010, 0.455, 0.980);
    /*-webkit-transition:all 2.0s easeInOutQuad;
    -moz-transition:all 2.0s easeInOutQuad;
    -o-transition:all 2.0s easeInOutQuad;
    transition:all 2.0s easeInOutQuad;*/
}
#slide1_images img {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:left;
}
.slider{
    float:left;
    width: 960px;
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT (Functions for next/previous/autorunning/sliding) -

```
var $selectedSlide=1;

//var autoSlider = setInterval(nextSlide, 5500);

function nextSlide() {
    if ($selectedSlide!=3) { 
        $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+-690 * ($selectedSlide)+"px)");
        $selectedSlide=$selectedSlide+1;
        //window.alert("SelectedSlide = "+$selectedSlide);
    }
    else {
        $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX(0px)");
        $selectedSlide=1;
    }
}

function prevSlide() {
    //clearInterval(autoSlider);
    if($selectedSlide>1) {
    $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX("+-690 * ($selectedSlide-2)+"px)");
    $selectedSlide=$selectedSlide-1;
    }
    else{
        $("#slide1_images").css("transform","translateX(-1380px)");
        $selectedSlide=3;
    }
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="sliderPrev">
<img src="images/SliderImages/SliderPrevBtn.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/SliderImages/SliderPrevBtnRollover.gif'"onmouseout="this.src='images/SliderImages/SliderPrevBtn.gif'" onClick="prevSlide();"/>
</div>
<div id="slide1_container" class="shadow" align="left">
  <div id="slide1_images" class="hover">
   <a href="BoldAndClassy.php" target="_blank"> <img src="images/SliderImages/SliderOne.jpg" class="noBorder"/></a>
   <a href="http://www.fubbie.tumblr.com" target="_blank"><img src="images/SliderImages/SliderTwo.jpg" class="noBorder"/></a>
   <a href="http://www.fubbie.tumblr.com" target="_blank"> <img src="images/SliderImages/SliderThree.jpg" class="noBorder"/></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="sliderNext">
<img src="images/SliderImages/SliderNextBtn.gif" onmouseover="this.src='images/SliderImages/SliderNextBtnRollover.gif'"onmouseout="this.src='images/SliderImages/SliderNextBtn.gif'" onClick="nextSlide();"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I wanted to let you know that I use Google Chrome, and I don't see the flickering on your site. I see a smooth transition from one image to the next.

Is it possible that you have an extension installed that's interfering in some way?

Here's the version string from the browser: Version 29.0.1547.57 m
I'm running on Windows 7

Comment: I just checked and I have zero extensions installed. And the transition used to be smooth for me (atleast I thought it was..), but I haven't made any changes to the slider and for some reason it is flickering for me. I have a Mac BTW, and we have the same version of chrome EXCEPT I do not have the "m" on the end? Possibly the m just differentiates the windows package from the mac package of chrome.